# Issue in AltBeacon Monitoring and Ranging android

Tags: android, monitoring, altbeacon, region-ranging

I am using this code for ranging and monitoring in Altbeacon

```
 class Appclass extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
private boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;
public static Region region1;
private static boolean activityVisible;
public static Appclass instances;
public static BeaconManager beaconManager;
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instances = this;beaconManager=org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

       beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1100l);
    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0l);
    beaconManager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(true);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(01);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100l);
    try {
        beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    Log.d("", "setting up background monitoring for beacons and power                 saving");
    // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
    region1 = new Region("backgroundRegion",
            null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region1);
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d("ABC", "Enter");
    Log.d("ABC value", region.getId2() + " " + region.getId3());
    try { Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AbcService.class);

            startService(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d("ABC", "exit");
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

}
```

and then in my AbcService class code is:

```
class AbcService extends Service implements BeaconConsumer, MonitorNotifier, RangeNotifier {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Appclass.beaconManager.bind(this);
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {
    Log.d("ABC", "range");
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    Appclass.beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(this);
    Appclass.beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);

}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    try {
        Log.d("ABC", "didEnterRegion");
        Log.d("ABC", "" + region.getId2() + region.getId3());
        Appclass.beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(Appclass.region1);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    try {
        Log.d("ABC", "didExitRegion");
         Appclass.beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(Appclass.region1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

}
```

}

now issue are getting that the `didEnterRegion` method of Application class calling every time when we enter in beacon range but the `didEnterRegion` method of AbcService class not calling some time and also not start ranging. what is the issue in my code?

Comment: In the service class does `didDetermineStateForRegion` get called?  Does `onBeaconServiceConnect()` get called?

Comment: it is calling some time...so i am not replicating what is the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I probably need more information to be helpful.  I'd suggest you try repeated tests, perhaps 10 times, and see which of these the methods in your service class, `onCreate`, `onBeaconServiceConnect`, and `didDetermineState` get called for each test run.  If you do these tests, please note any patterns you notice in which methods get called vs. the conditions under test.

Comment: 'onBeaconServiceConnect' and 'onCreate' calling but didEnter and didExit not calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few tips:

- Start ranging the same time as you start monitoring.  There is no reason to wait for an entered region callback or to stop ranging when you exit the region.
- Add logging to `didDetermineStateFirRegion`.  This method gets called when a beacon appears after app startup even if the device was already in region from when it was previously running.  `didEnterRegion` only gets called if beacons matching the region actually disappear for 15+ seconds and then reappear.

Comment: Done . thanks davidgyoung. i start ranging again from 'didDetermineStateFirRegion' this method and its working fine.